# Find : $\min P=2x^2-xy-y^2$?

Tags: inequality, optimization

$x;y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that : $x^2+2xy+3y^2=4$.

> Find : $\min P=2x^2-xy-y^2$ ?

Thanks :)

P/s : I have no ideas about this problem ! :(

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try using the Lagrange multiplier method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use $y = \sqrt2 \sin \theta, \; x + y = 2 \cos \theta$ and simplify to get 
$P = 6- 5\sqrt2 \sin (2 \theta)+2 \cos (2 \theta)$, then the minimum is obviously $6 - \sqrt{54}$.

Comment: Interesting approach.  Can you explain how you found the substitutions?

Comment: @DanielV We can notice that the constraint can be restated as $(x+y)^2+ 2y^2=4$. From this form, the trigonometric substitution seems reasonable to try.